# Polymer 2.0 and multiple slots

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, custom-element

I want to build a Polymer 2.0 custom element DOM tree, but I want to just populate the children (the slots) based on the tag type of each child, so when I'm writing the HTML to use my custom elements **don't** want to write:

```
  <group>
    <title slot="title">admins</title>
    <description slot="description">some description</description>
    <users slot="users">
      <user slot="user">
        <name slot="name">Amy</name>
        <dept slot="dept">Widgets</dept>
        <phone slot="phone">1234</phone>
      </user>
      <user slot="user">
        <name slot="name">Bill</name>
        <dept slot="dept">Sprockets</dept>
        <phone slot="phone">5678</phone>
      </user>
      <user slot="user">
        <name slot="name">Chris</name>
        <dept slot="dept">Rachets</dept>
        <phone slot="phone">1357</phone>
      </user>
    </users>
  </group>
```

This should work using named slots in Polymer 2.0, but you can see it's very cumbersome and redundant if you have a deep tree where every level has several properties.

What I really want to do instead is just write:

```
  <group>
    <title>admins</title>
    <description>some description</description>
    <users>
      <user>
        <name>Amy</name>
        <dept>Widgets</dept>
        <phone>1234</phone>
      </user>
      <user>
        <name>Bill</name>
        <dept>Sprockets</dept>
        <phone>5678</phone>
      </user>
      <user>
        <name>Chris</name>
        <dept>Rachets</dept>
        <phone>1357</phone>
      </user>
    </users>
  </group>
```

which is essentially just XML. This seems much easier to work with than the first example to me. As you can see with the named slots, as the tree gets deeper it gets very crowded and messy.

So my question is how can I do the latter example in Polymer 2.0? Is it even possible? It seems to me that this would be a prime use case for Polymer so there really should be a way to achieve it. The closest I found was this web page, but it doesn't really do what I want cause you are limited to one "default" slot per custom element template:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#slots

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what are you trying to archieve here, you sure you don't really want `dom-repeat` instead? It looks to me you just want to list some elements based on the XML you posted.

Comment: Only downside is that you can't repeat slots easily. Probably the thing I miss most when using Polymer. I tend to use iron-list instead for the template.

Comment: I think what I actually want here is to be able to set properties. I realize you can do that via HTML attributes, but I actually want to set one or more properties that are themselves custom elements, and can't be represented via text attributes in the opening tag - they need to be child elements instead. So my question is really more about how I can map several different custom elements from HTML inner element tags into properties and then onto the shadow DOM.

Comment: I'm still unsure what is the purpose of `slots` in this case. What is the end result that you want to archieve here?

Comment: Taking the top level node as an example, I want to render the <group> with 3 different properties in different places, e.g. <h2>title</h2>, <p>description<p> and then a list for the users. And then for each user I want to be able to do the same for their respective fields. I'm not sure how I can do this (if at all) using my 2nd code example.